# Error when add attendees in new calendar event

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

log error in odoo when I try add new attendee in calendar event

[image: attendees error]

```
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/tools/cache.py", line 74, in lookup
value = d[key] = self.method(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 901, in xmlid_lookup
raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % (xmlid))
ValueError: External ID not found in the system: calendar.calendar_template_meeting_invitation
```

Comment: You need to show the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the **calendar** module, because Meeting Invitation Email template may be deleted.